# Remove new kernel 5.8.* from Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, networking, kernel, xubuntu, uninstall

Kernel 5.8.0-41 was loaded during an update.  It later updated to 5.8.0-44.
When I boot my Dell XP15 9550 with upgraded Intel 9260 wifi/bluetooth module installed, neither wifi nor usb adaptor to RJ45 networking works.
Networking is good using kernel 5.4.*

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.8*
```

deletes linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic and linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic but then installs linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-44-generic.
Removing this installs linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic

How do I delete all 5.8 kernels to prevent future updating, so that I keep booting with 5.4?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just fix the networking?

Comment: The Intel 9260 requires a newer kernel, not an older one. You can try https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/ (not the lowlatency files). It may also require updated firmware from the intel web site.

Comment: Thank you for looking. The 5.4 kernels all work fine, the later 5.8 kernels have the problem.

Comment: While booted into 5.8, please run: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic | grep Status` Next, edit your question to show the result.

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

> **Desktop**
>
> It is advised to keep Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS with the kernel flavour
> picked during installation. It can be either HWE or OEM flavour.
> Changing to track GA kernel may result in regressions of performance,
> hardware support, and certified features.
>
> To check if you are on a certified hardware platform execute:
>
> `ubuntu-drivers list-oem`
>
> If any meta packages are listed, please refrain from manually changing
> the kernel flavours.
> To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:
>
> `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic`
>
> If NVIDIA drivers are required check appropriate level and install
> them:
>
> `ubuntu-drivers list`
>
> And then install appropriate NNN version of the drivers:
>
> `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-modules-nvidia-NNN-generic`
>
> Reboot, interrupt grub, in advanced options elect to boot 5.4 based
> kernel, complete boot. Check that everything works as expected.
>
> If everything is good, you may remove the other kernel flavours:
>
> `sudo apt remove --purge linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-oem-20.04 linux-hwe-* linux-oem-* linux-modules-5.1* linux-modules-5.8.0-* linux-modules-5.6.0-*`

Comment: This answer is just copy & pasted from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack    I'd always suggest reading the official documentation first, and come to sites such as this if you have trouble understanding something.  It looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  As it happened, after playing with deleting kernels, other issues occurred, and I decided that instead of addressing them, it was quicker and easier to reload Xubuntu 20.04 as a new installation, as almost all data is on other partitions and drives.  Now everything is working sweetly.